# How to use variable in child class to create a sequence in base class in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have class defined as such below

```
class Type(Base):
     """
     Base class for "Type" tables
     "Type" tables are basically configuration tables with:
        key ====> id
        value ====> name
     Example usage:
         class RelationShipStatus(Type):
             __tablename__ = "relationship_status"
             __sequencename__ = "relationship_status_seq"


    status = RelationShipStatus()
    status.name = "Blocked"
    persist(status)

    Ensure to abstract the __tablename__ and __sequencename__ variables 
    to customise them
    __sequencename__ HAS to be defined in the child class
    __tablename__ is a magic sqlalchemy variable that will always have 
    to be defined in the child class
    """

    __abstract__ = True

    __sequencename__ = ""

    id = Column(
        SmallInteger, Sequence(__sequencename__),
        primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Unicode(20), unique=True)
    description = Column(Unicode(50))

    def __repr__(self):
        return ''' <{class_name}(id={self.id},name=
        {self.name})>'''.format(
        self=self, class_name=self.__class__.__name__)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

When I define a child class as

```
class RelationshipType(Type):
   __tablename__ = "relationship_type"
   __sequencename__ = "rel_type_seq"
```

I get an error.

```
File "/home/vagrant/env/flask_files_api/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py", line 2880, in _requires_quotes
  lc_value = value.lower()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'`
```

How do i get the parent class to use the `__sequencename__` as defined in the child class? I need the sequence name to be as i defined it in the child class

Comment: what error? and why `RelationshipType(Base)` instead of `RelationshipType(Type)`?

Comment: `File "/home/vagrant/env/flask_files_api/local/lib/python2.7/site-
    packages/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py", line 2880, in _requires_quotes
      lc_value = value.lower()
     AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'`                          I have edited the code. RelationshipType now sublcasses Type

Comment: Are you using Oracle? If not, there's no point in manually defining sequences, most of the time.

Comment: @IljaEverilä I'm using PostgresSQL

Comment: In that case unless [manually reflecting an existing schema, i.e. using a specific sequence](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html#sequences-serial), just pass `autoincrement=True` to your primary key column (not strictly required, as SQLAlchemy will use SERIAL for integer based primary key columns by default).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is the [`@declared_attr`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative/api.html#sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.declared_attr) decorator:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declared_attr

class Type(Base):
    ...
    @declared_attr
    def id(cls):
        return Column(SmallInteger,
                      Sequence(cls.__sequencename__),
                      primary_key=True)
```

This way you defer the actual creation of the column to when the subclass is defined:

> `@declared_attr` turns the attribute into a scalar-like property that can be invoked from the uninstantiated class. Declarative treats attributes specifically marked with `@declared_attr` as returning a construct that is specific to mapping or declarative table configuration. The name of the attribute is that of what the non-dynamic version of the attribute would be.

Now, if not [using Oracle](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/oracle.html#auto-increment-behavior), manually defining sequences is to my understanding mostly unnecessary. You should just add `autoincrement=True` to your primary key column, or leave it at its [default value of `"auto"`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.params.autoincrement):

> The default value is the string `"auto"` which indicates that a single-column primary key that is of an INTEGER type with no stated client-side or python-side defaults should receive auto increment semantics automatically

Comment: Thanks..let me try this out.

Comment: Works perfectly!! Thanks. @Ilja Everila